# how perform batch operation with dapper orm?

Tags: orm, batch-file, dapper, bulk

I Have dapper orm in project and i have save alto of data (1200000row) in database but in transaction with dapper is very slow i want fast.with nhibernate (session statetless)is slow.
I think dapper is fast because that fetch data(700000) with nhibernate in 33 second that with dapper in 9 second.

how solved problem ?

my code is :

```
IDbTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
connection.Execute(@"
    insert DailyResult(Id, PersonId,DateTaradod,DailyTaradods)
    values(@Id, @PersonId,@DateTaradod,@DailyTaradods)", entity, trans);                                    
trans.Commit();
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no mechanism to make inserting 1200000 rows in a transaction instant, via *any* regular ADO.NET API. That simply *isn't what the intent of that API is*.

For what you want, it sounds like you should be using `SqlBulkCopy`. This supports transactions, and you can use [`FastMember`](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) to help here; for example:

```
IEnumerable<YourEntity> source = ...
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(
    connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(source,
         "Id", "PersonId", "DateTaradod", "DailyTaradods"))
{
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "DailyResult";
    bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
}
```

It also supports *external* transactions, but if you are going to "create tran, push, commit tran" you might as well use the internal transaction.

If you don't want to use `SqlBulkCopy`, you can also look at table-valued-parameter approaches, but `SqlBulkCopy` would be my *recommended* API when dealing with this volume.

Note: if the table has more columns than `Id`, `PersonId`, `DateTaradod` and `DailyTaradods`, you can specify explicit `bcp.ColumnMappings` to tweak how the insert behaves.

Comment: Thank you very mouch.But use of sqlbulk my project dependency for database sqlserver I want my project run in  oracle,

Comment: @zahraahmadi if only there was an [`OracleBulkCopy` class](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm)...